# Routing with Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

This is my controller Code :

```
public class MenuController : ApiController
    {      
        [Route("api/menu/setorder"),HttpPost()]
        public HttpResponseMessage SetOrder(string orders)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
     }
```

And this is the routing section in `WebApiConfig` :

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

When I tried to call the action with this code I got 404 Not Found Error :

```
  var uri = 'api/menu/setorder';

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.post(uri, { orders: "13_12-31:3" })
                .done(function (data) {                    
                    $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                        console.log(item["id"]);
                    });
                });
        });
```

How should i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Look at the section "Routing By Action Name".